# Find offset and scaling of 2 curves (solve linear problem)

Tags: python, linear-algebra, curve-fitting, curve, scipy-optimize-minimize

I've got 2 curves that have an offset and scaling, which I would like to know.
Now finding a factor without offset would not be to hard, as solving Curve1*a = Curve2 is not to hard.
Also the offset, solving Curve1+b = Curve2 is not the problem.

It just a linear problem, however, i get stuck when looking for Curve1*a +b = Curve2.

I looked into scipy.minimize, and np.solve, but I'm having a hard time with it.

So I'm trying to minimize f(a,b) = (Curve1*a + b) - Curve2. I can't figure out how.

So imagine craeting two curves;

```py
t = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1);
c1 = np.sin(t)
c2 = c1*2.5 + 4
```

I want to get a=2.5 and b=4.
I tried creating a function

```py
def func(x, c1,c2):
    x1=x[0]
    x2=x[1]
    y= np.mean(c1 - (c2*x1 + x2))
    return y
```

Then minimizing it

```py
x_start = [2, 10]
result = scipy.optimize.minimize(func, c1, c2, x_start)
```

But I don't think this is really the correct way, plus it errors
`ttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'`

If anyone could help me out, that would be really appreciated! :)

Comment: I think the documentation of `minimize()` would help. Your function should take the `x` which is 1-D array with the shape of (n,) as the first argument. You can check the doc here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html

Comment: This depends on how the two curves are defined. If they are given on the form of data  is the number of points the same (or different) from one curve to the other ? To be concrete you should joint to the question an example of couple of data.

Comment: @DasaniT , I can't get it to work.. I can't find examples where 2 curves are used, and I'm doing someting wrong..

Comment: @JJacquelin I added some extra information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were not far from the solution but I have found at least three problems in your code.

1. You are not giving the arguments to the `minimize()` method correctly :

   `scipy.optimize.minimize(func,x_start,args=(c1,c2))`
2. You have inverted c1 and c2 in the error function `func()`
3. Given the residuals `y= c2 - (c1*x1 + x2)` can be either positive or negative, calculate their sum or their mean is not a good marker for the discrepancy between c2 and the optimization. You should better calculate the sum of the square of the residual `return np.sum(y*y)`. This way you will perform a least square minimisation.

Finally I have this code working :

```
import scipy
import scipy.optimize
import numpy as np

t = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1);
c1 = np.sin(t)
c2 = c1*2.5 + 4

    def func(x,c1,c2):

    x1=x[0]
    x2=x[1]
    y= c2 - (c1*x1 + x2)
    return np.sum(y*y)


x_start = [2, 10]
result = scipy.optimize.minimize(func,x_start,args=(c1,c2))
print(result)
```

This gives :

```
fun: 6.604621880500689e-15
 hess_inv: array([[ 0.01133786, -0.00211422],
       [-0.00211422,  0.00539425]])
      jac: array([-9.06677028e-13, -3.57935903e-13])
  message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nfev: 32
      nit: 5
     njev: 8
   status: 0
  success: True
        x: array([2.5       , 3.99999999])
```